# Mysql: How to aggregate data into days based on half hourly timestamps?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

The question sounds more complex than it probably is. I have a very simple table with php timestamps (just integers, not MySQL Date Fields) and float values.

```
id | timestamp | values |
```

The values are stored in half hourly intervals, so each timestamp increments by half an hour.

I would like to aggregate a weeks worth of data into days in one query, so the response looks a something like this (1317596400 = OCT 3RD 2011)

```
0 | 1317596400 | 10.5
1 | 1317682800 | 9.65
2 | 1317769200 | 8.1
3 | 1317855600 | 9.6
4 | 1317942000 | 10.11
5 | 1318028400 | 12.1
6 | 1318114800 | 11.8
```

Where timestamp is 00:00 or 12:00, anything to identify the day.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I made some progress...

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as stamp, sum(data) FROM energy 
WHERE
timestamp >= 1317423600
AND
timestamp <= 1320105600
GROUP BY (  DATE( stamp ) )
```

<strike>but this seems to be limiting the response to a month. I don't seem to be able to query from the middle of 1 month to the the middle of another month.</strike>

Group by "Date" not "Day", otherwise you end up summing the values of (for example) May 1st and April 1st into one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your days are UTC days, you can `GROUP BY (timestamp - timestamp % 86400)`

The short formula rounds the timestamp down to the nearest whole day, albeit whole days starting at 00:00 UTC.

This avoids the conversion from UNIX epoch to a `DATETIME` value.

Comment: Nice tip on the rounding down of timestamps. Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most difficult part is to parse the integer to a date in string.

you could do it like this  DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( 1317596400  ) )

Comment: "FROM_UNIXTIME" really helped here. However, it seems encapsulating it in DATE isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the timestamp into a date, truncate the date to midnight and then convert it back into a timestamp value. A bit like this:

```
select unix_timestamp(date(from_unixtime(timestamp))) as "phpDate",
sum(someValues) as "values"
from myTable
group by phpDate;
```

Hope I've got the right end of the stick here!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the timestamps to something MySQL can use, then group the results by date.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) as stamp, sum(data) FROM energy 
WHERE
timestamp >= 1317423600
AND
timestamp <= 1320105600
GROUP BY (  DATE( stamp ) )
```